# Can Mathematica read planar graphs with pc format?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

We can download files about some special planar graphs  at the following website, but their files are suffixed with pc.

- [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/planegraphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/planegraphs.html)

I don't know how to read them. When I tried to open the file, the contents were garbled.

[image]

It feels like they're binaries. *Mathematica* does a great job of reading the Graph6 format. But is there any hope of reading against this format in this web.

---

Here's what I tried. For eample, I tried to read a 12-vertex 5-regular planar graph. But I don't understand what output means.

```
BinaryReadList["D:/5reg_12-20.pc"]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you need a plantri program for that https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/

Comment: Thanks. I know the plantri program. But some sepcail planar graphs in above web are not easily to be obtained by plantri,  as stated on the web page. So I thought it would be easier to just read it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to generate these planar graphs using the `plantri` program and ask for Graph6 output, which Mathematica can read (and IGraph/M can read faster). However, Graph6 does not encode the combinatorial embedding like the pc format does. The following is a small function that decodes this format to combinatorial embeddings:

```
decode[data_] :=
 Module[{d = data, head, vc, g},
  (* skip header if it exists *)
  head = ToCharacterCode[">>planar_code<<"];
  If[Take[d, Min[Length[d], Length[head]]] === head,
    d = Drop[d, Length[head]];
  ];
  (* split data at zero separators *)
  d = Most /@ Split[d, #1 =!= 0 &];
  First@Last@Reap@While[Length[d] > 0,
      vc = d[[1, 1]]; (* vertex count *)
      (* get as many neighbour lists as the vertex count *)
      {g, d} = TakeDrop[d, vc];
      (* drop vertex count from first neighbour list *)
      g = MapAt[Rest, g, {1}];
      (* build association for combinatorial embedding *)
      Sow@AssociationThread[Range[vc], Reverse /@ g (* reverse from clockwise to counterclockwise *)]
      ]
  ]
```

Note that there is no error checking! If you are interested in a robust version, feel free to [open a feature request for IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues/new/choose), and I will consider including it in the next version.

The expected input is the contents of a *valid* PC file, as a list of bytes (values between 0..255).

Example:

```
data = Import[
  "http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/5reg_20-32.pc", "Byte"]

decode[data]
```

This returns a list of associations, each representing a graph and its combinatorial embedding. The format is the same that IGraph/M uses, which I think you are familiar with: vertices are associated with a list of their counter-clockwise neighbours.

You can use `IGAdjacencyGraph` to convert this format to a graph or `IGEmbeddingToCoordinates` to get planar coordinates for them.

In the following example I chose to use a Tutte layout instead, as it is visually more appealing:

```
IGLayoutTutte@IGAdjacencyGraph[#] & /@ decode[data]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, although I don't know why your code works, right. but it deserves to be a new function in the next version of IGraph/M.